# Settings for cache and proxy with Vesta Control Panel in a Drupal site

Tags: 7

In a site powered by Drupal 7 and a Vesta Control Panel I have a problem with cache, or proxy settings. When a visitor respons to a poll, the IP recorded is the IP from the servor, not from the anonymous user. I have the same problem in a Webform contact page, the IP is not from the sender.

In Vesta Control Panel, I have check "Support ProxyNGINX" and select "caching". I have the same problem with another site with NGINX desactivated in Vesta.

Thx for your help